# How to sort a TEXT Date Column in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, calculated-columns, date-sorting

I have data :- 31-May-07

Its in a calculated column of the list. The method I used to get it :- =IF(FDate="","",TEXT(FDate,"dd-mmm-yy")) {FDate is a DateTime type of column. The returned value is stored in a "Single Line of Text" column type.}

I am now unable to sort that column as its Text now and sorting is done on basis of strings.

I need to sort this column on basis of Date.

Any help ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Sharepoint but this looks like a pure Excel question. I presume you don't really want to convert the date into text. Let it be a date and just change the cell format.

Comment: The original date column has :- 31/05/2007. In sharepoint I havent found a date format to convert where it display the name of the month. So need it to convert in string. Now I want sorting for it. But cant make a formulae for Date based sorting.

Comment: @Vaibhav S, you can mark my answer as accepted (given that it was of any help) or post your own answer if you found the solution yourself.